# Project inspection in VS Code

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, phpstorm

I'm a big fan of PhpStorm and have been trying to find an alternative to it. I'm a big fan of VS Code but was wondering is there a tool plugin anyone can recommend that will provide project inspection as is done in PhpStorm?

For example: I would type:

```
new My/NameSpace/ClassName
```

it would sense this and import the class.

Or

```
$object->
```

then it would provide a list of all available functions within that object?

I don't know if I'm asking a lot from VSCode? I have several plugins but none seem to do it, perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: I found 6 extensions when I searched for PhPStorm in the VScode marketplace. Have you checked any of them?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I did try them. There were quite a few doing the same kind of things. I found one that actually works! it's called "PHP Intellisense - Crane"

Answer (score 1):

I found one that works and gives the functionality I was after. It's called **"PHP Intellisense - Crane"**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HvyIndustries.crane

Enjoy